# Got error while running Calendar Api Sample Code

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

Was trying to implement Google Calendar Code taken from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java but got an error as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/jetty/Handler
at CalendarQuickstart.authorize(CalendarQuickstart.java:76)
at CalendarQuickstart.getCalendarService(CalendarQuickstart.java:89)
at CalendarQuickstart.main(CalendarQuickstart.java:101)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.Handler
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

And the line was

```
 Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
        flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

Before this i just copied code from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java and created a Java Project and this two Jar file was missing

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
```

After importing these jar file got that error. Please help

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Calendar API Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java)  works fine. Based on the error message you received, it looks like you're missing one of the jetty dependencies. If you're using [Gradle](http://gradle.org/gradle-download/) build (as suggested in [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java#step_2_prepare_the_project), check under your "Gradle Depenencies" for this jar file -`jetty-6.1.26.jar`.

If you're missing the jetty dependencies, Open your `build.gradle` and check to make sure you have included all the dependencies listed below.

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
     compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.20.0'
     compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0'
}
```

Finally, Build and run the Gradle file to download the missing dependencies. You should now be up and running ! :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answering. But i am not using gradle build. I am trying to run with .jar file but not getting exact jar file and i tried with the jar file you mentioned above but same problem occurs.

Comment: @Rahul Sometimes it helps if you try removing all the libraries and running the build manifest (if it's Maven or Ant) from scratch and clean the project after the build. There maybe something botched up in your workspace that is unable to find the JAR files.